# Python User Input

Tags: input, python-3.x

I am using this code to find numbers that are not multiples of 2 or 3. I would like to be able to have the user input the length of the list of the numbers instead of setting it to a specific number like I did here with 6. How would I allow the user to input a specified length?

```
b = []
i = 1

while len(b)< 6:
    b.append(6*i-1) 
    b.append(6*i+1)
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.X : Doc [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

```
input_var = raw_input("Enter something: ")
print "you entered ", input_var
```

Python 3.X : (`raw_input` was renamed `input` in Python 3.X)

```
input_var = input("Enter something: ")
print ("you entered " + input_var)
```

Which gives:

```
b = []
i = 1

str = input("Enter something: ") 
n = int(str)                       # Get an integer
print ("you entered " + str) 

while (len(b) < n):
    b.append(n * i - 1) 
    b.append(n * i + 1)
    i += 1
```

Result (with 12):

```
>>> print(b)
[11, 13, 23, 25, 35, 37, 47, 49, 59, 61, 71, 73]
```

Comment: I would like to incorporate it in the while loop... instead of me putting the 6 in this statement....while len(b)<6...I want something like...while len(b)< n.... where n is the value that the user input for the length of the list.

Comment: Yep, got it. I edited my answer... Tell me if there is something you do not understand. `input()` returns a string, that we turn into an integer using `int()`. Then we are good to use `n` in the loop.

Comment: I tried that and I keep getting the error....                                         while (len(b) < n):
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Comment: Because I made a mistake in the first place (forgot to turn the string into int before use). Please, grab the updated code from the answer again. That one works.

Comment: Sorry but have another question...when I enter an odd number for n it gives me a list of the next largest even number...so if I enter 5 instead of giving me 5 numbers in the list it gives me 6.

Comment: Sorry, but this is another matter, unrelated to the initial question. Please, ask another question, or find out by yourself. By the way this kind of algorithmic question is probably more suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).